# Loading childrens with properties[Eager Loading] with Nuxeo Rest Api

Tags: java, rest, nuxeo

> 1) http://host:port/nuxeo/api/v1/path/default-domain/workspaces/Report

gives me basic content of Report document

> 2)http://host:port/nuxeo/api/v1/path/default-domain/workspaces/Report?properties=*

gives me basic+all properties of Report document

> 3)http://host:port/nuxeo/api/v1/path/default-domain/workspaces/Report?enrichers.document=children

gives me basic content of Report document and all its children document with its basic content

> 4)http://host:port/nuxeo/api/v1/path/default-domain/workspaces/Report?enrichers.document=children&properties=*

gives me basic+all properties of Report document and all its children document with its basic content

**Now how can I get properties of all its children as well?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.We need to specify 'depth' header to control aggregation depth

Though documentation suggest depth is set to **children** by default. But for me
specifying **"depth"** explicitly to **"children"** or **"max"** worked

```
http://host:port/nuxeo/api/v1/path/default-domain/workspaces/Report?enrichers.document=children&properties=*&depth=children
```